# Remove degree $4$ term from quintic?

Tags: polynomials

If I have a quintic polynomial $$p(x) = x^5 + bx^4 + cx^3 + dx^2 + ex + f$$what variable substitution could I make that would allow me to remove the $bx^4$ term, producing a different polynomial in the form $$q(t) = gt^5 + ht^3 + jt^2 + kt + m$$ where $g$, $h$, $j$, $k$, and $m$ can be expressed in terms of $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, and $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do $x=y-\frac b5$. Since $\left(y-\frac b5\right)^5=y^5-by^4+\cdots$ and $b\left(y-\frac b5\right)^4=by^4+\cdots$, when you expand everything no term with degree $4$ will remain.

Comment: Indeed.  $-b$ is the sum of the five roots (Vieta). The transformed equation has sum of roots zero. If the roots are all changed by the same amount it needs to be $\frac b5$ and you just need to get the sign right. [This is just a note to record a passing observation which helped me to remember what is going on - the algebra/manipulation is, of course, easy]

Comment: Great! Just a question about doing this. I am actually trying to isolate the roots of p(x), but the algorithm I am using (isolator polynomials) requires there to be no x^4 term. Once I've transformed p(x) into q(t), and used the isolator algorithm to bracket the roots of q(t), is it as simple as "shifting" each value that I got from this algorithm backwards (i.e. negative) b/5 to go back from "t" to "x"?

Comment: @GaryAllen Yes: if $t_0$ is root of $q(t)$, then, since $q(t)=p\left(t-\frac b5\right)$, $t_0+\frac b5$ is a root of $p(t)$.